# Fill an array of struct dynamically

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have this structure:

```
struct Vertex {
    Vertex(float px, float py, float pz,
           float nx, float ny, float nz,
           float tx, float ty) : position(px, py, pz),
                                 normals(nx, ny, nz),
                                 texCoords(tx, ty) {}
    XMFLOAT3 position;
    XMFLOAT3 normals;
    XMFLOAT2 texCoords;
};
```

and I need to fill an array of that with some vectors:

```
std::vector<XMFLOAT3> positions;
std::vector<XMFLOAT3> normals;
std::vector<XMFLOAT2> texCoords;
```

The length of the array is given by

```
int numVertices;
```

I' d like to fill the array of `struct Vertex` with the vectors given. How can I do that?
I tried to initialize the array in this way:

```
Vertex points[numVertices];
```

but that var does not have a constant value.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why can't you use `std::vector<Vertex>`?

Comment: After that I have to use `reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(points)` which takes arrays and not vectors.

Comment: `vector::data()` acts like a raw array (a pointer to its first element to be precise). You can use it to cast to `BYTE*` or whatever.

Comment: Also @Pino technically `reinterpret_cast` doesn't take array but it takes pointer by implicit `array-to-pointer conversion` - [8.2.10 expr.reinterpret.cast](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#1)

Comment: Alright. Thanks for your help. One more thing: If I had to fill the n-element of the `std::vector<Vertex>` with the concatenation of the n-element of positions, normals and texCoords, how can I do that?

Comment: Like `vec.push_back(Vertex(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8));` for example if that's your only constructor of `Vertex`. *That's for pushing back not the n-th, I didn't spot.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::vector` is the best option to create a dynamic array.

1. It takes care of memory management for you.
2. You can access the contents of the array using `std::vector::data`, `std::vector::operator[]`, `std::vector::iterator`.
3. You can process each element of a `std::vector` using a range-`for` loop.

Instead of

```
Vertex points[numVertices];
```

use

```
std::vector<Vertex> points(numVertices);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must use raw arrays, you can try this. Assuming XMFLOAT3, XMFLOAT2 is something like follows:

```
struct XMFLOAT3 {
    XMFLOAT3(float x, float y, float z) : _x(x), _y(y), _z(z) {};
    float _x;
    float _y;
    float _z;
};

struct XMFLOAT2 {
    XMFLOAT2(float x, float y) : _x(x), _y(y) {};
    float _x;
    float _y;
};
```

define an init function to initialize Vertex array by dynamically allocating and initializing the elements as:

```
Vertex **
initVertex(int numVertices)
{
    Vertex **points = new Vertex *[numVertices];
    for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; ++i) {
        points[i] = new Vertex(positions[i]._x, positions[i]._y, positions[i]._x,
                normals[i]._x, normals[i]._y, normals[i]._z,
                texCoords[i]._x, texCoords[i]._y);
    }
    return points;
}
```

You can use `Vertex **points = initVertex(numVertices)` and dereference each element.

If you must have `Vertex *points` then you can use this function to create the initialized array of Vertices:

```
Vertex *
initVertex2(int numVertices)
{
    char *points_buf = new char[sizeof(Vertex) * numVertices];
    Vertex *points = reinterpret_cast<Vertex *>(points_buf);
    for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; ++i) {
        new (points_buf + i * sizeof(Vertex))
                Vertex(positions[i]._x, positions[i]._y, positions[i]._x,
                normals[i]._x, normals[i]._y, normals[i]._z,
                texCoords[i]._x, texCoords[i]._y);
    }
    return points;
}
```

And call it `Vertex *points = initVertex2(numVertices)` and use array indexing to access each element.